# Не получается отправить mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, smtp

Делаю так:

```
public static void SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("***@gmail.com",email);
    mail.Body = message;
    mail.Subject = subject;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",465);
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***@gmail.com", "mypass");  
    try
    {
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exception ex2 = ex;
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        while (ex2 != null)
        {
            errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
            ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
        }                
    }
}
```

Вылетает в `catch` с сообщением

> {System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>      at site.EmailService.SendEmailAsync(String email, String subject, String message) in C:\Users\Виталий\source\repos\site\site\EmailService.cs:line 64}

Помогите разобраться в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему, проблема в порте, должно быть 587 а не 465:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
```

[Read Gmail messages on other email clients using POP](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&visit_id=636812338866803852-3176557649&rd=1)

Comment: Спасибище :) Самое интересное то - что я подсмотрел данный порт в гугл хелпере, но да ладно

Answer (score 1):

Готовый рабочий класс (работает уже больше 5 лет)

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace AeroAdmin
    {

public class clsMail
{
    public static string Subject
    {
        set{m_subject=value;}
    }

    public static string To_name
    {
        set{m_to_name=value;}
    }

    public static string To_mail
    {
        set{m_to_mail="<"+value+">";}
    }
    public static string From_name
    {
        set{m_from_name=value;}
    }

    public static string From_mail
    {
        set{m_from_mail="<"+value+">";}
    }

    public static string SmtpServer
    {
        set{smtpServer=value;}
    }

    public static int SmtpPort
    {
        set{smtpPort=value;}
    }

    public static List<string> Mail_body
    {
        set{mail_body=value;}
    }

    public static string Mail_date
    {
        set{m_date=value;}
    }

    private static string m_subject;
    private static string m_to_name;
    private static string m_to_mail;
    private static string m_from_name;
    private static string m_from_mail;
    private static string smtpServer;
    private static string m_date;
    private static int smtpPort;

    private static List<string> mail_body;

    public static void Send()
    {
        // generate an RFC compliant email

        // Заголовок
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("Subject: {0}", m_subject);
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        sb.AppendFormat("To: {0}{1}", m_to_name, m_to_mail);
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        sb.AppendFormat("From: {0}{1}", m_from_name, m_from_mail);
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        //sb.AppendFormat("Date: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, d MMM yyyy H:m:s zz00"));
        sb.AppendFormat("Date: {0}",m_date);
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        //sb.AppendFormat("Content-Type: text/plain");
        sb.AppendLine("Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"Unicode\"");
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        //sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        // Тело письма
        for(int i=0;i<mail_body.Count;i++)
        {
            sb.Append(mail_body[i]);
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

        string email = sb.ToString();

        // Отправка письма с использованием сокета
        ///////////////////////////////////////////

        TcpClient client = null;

        try
        {
            // Установка соединения
            client = new TcpClient(smtpServer, smtpPort);
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            StreamReader stdIn  = new StreamReader(ns);
            StreamWriter stdOut = new StreamWriter(ns);

            // Ждем ответа сервера
            int responseCode = GetResponse(stdIn);
            if (responseCode != 220)
                throw new Exception("no smtp server at specified address or smtp server not ready");

            // Посылаем команду HELO
            stdOut.WriteLine("HELO " + Dns.GetHostName());
            stdOut.Flush();
            responseCode = GetResponse(stdIn);
            if (responseCode != 250)
                throw new Exception("helo fails. code="+responseCode);

            // Команда MAIL
            stdOut.WriteLine("MAIL FROM:"+m_from_mail);
            stdOut.Flush();
            responseCode = GetResponse(stdIn);
            if (responseCode != 250)
                throw new Exception("FROM email considered bad by server. code="+responseCode);

            // Команда RCPT 
            stdOut.WriteLine("RCPT TO:"+m_to_mail);
            stdOut.Flush();
            responseCode = GetResponse(stdIn);
            switch(responseCode)
            {
                case 250:
                case 251:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("TO email considered bad by server. code="+responseCode);
            }

            // Команда DATA 
            stdOut.WriteLine("DATA");
            stdOut.Flush();
            responseCode = GetResponse(stdIn);
            if (responseCode != 354)
                throw new Exception("data command not accepted. code="+responseCode);

            // Отправка
            stdOut.WriteLine(email);
            stdOut.Flush();

            // Отправка одиночной точки означает завершение отправки
            stdOut.WriteLine(".");
            stdOut.Flush();
            responseCode = GetResponse(stdIn);
            if (responseCode != 250)
                throw new Exception("email not accepted. code="+responseCode);

            // Команда QUIT
            stdOut.WriteLine("QUIT");
            stdOut.Flush();
            responseCode = GetResponse(stdIn);
            if (responseCode != 221)
            {
                //who cares
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Все успешно отправлено");


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Закрываем соединение
            if (client != null)
                client.Close();
            client = null;
        }
    }

    static int GetResponse(StreamReader stdIn)
    {
        try
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            // Читаем ответ сервера
            do
            {
                response += stdIn.ReadLine()+"\r\n";
            }
            while(stdIn.Peek() != -1);

            // Получаем код ответа (первые три символа)
            return Convert.ToInt32(response.Substring(0, 3));
        }
        catch
        {
            // Если ошибка
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Зачем вы работаете с почтовиком на таком низком уровне, когда майкрософт представляет пару готовых библиотек со всем необходимым?

Comment: Этот код не будет работать с такими почтовиками как gmail или mail.ru, так как они требуют защищенного соединения, которое включается командой STARTTLS

Comment: автор, ты меня извени, но суть сайта в том чтобы исправлять мои ошибки по данному вопросу, а не делать с нуля новые. В благодарность за потраченное время на меня +1 тебя. Спасибо.